# Does Wubi work on Aspire One with Windows 8 pre-installed?

Tags: windows, wubi, windows-8, aspire, aspire-one

I bought an Aspire One 725 pre-loaded with Windows 8 (I didn't know what I was getting into). I am a novice when it comes to installing operating systems, so I would like to use a Windows installer so that I don't screw everything up and to try out a Linux distro.

Is there one that will work on this computer? I would like to use `wubi.exe`, but I've heard that it may or may not work.

Comment: You're actually less likely to screw anything up by using a LiveCD or bootable USB :P. Also, since - as far as I know - the `wubi.exe` installer doesn't partition your hard-drive, they can potentially cause conflicts and isn't how Ubuntu is intended to work. If I were you, I'd install it the normal way - but best of luck doing this nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The Acer Aspire One netbook [has been awarded the status of Certified for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200908-3469/).  There should be no issue, go a head and download Wubi and install it.

---

I found an Aspire user who [posted this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090982).  Basically, you must do the following:

- Install the 64-bit (not 32-bit!) version or else there will be errors and laggy animation.
- At the login screen, you must enable the touchpad by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.  You can then enable two-button scrolling from Settings > Mouse > Touchpad.
- For screen dimming and 3Dyou must install the latest AMD Catalyst driver from [here](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta11-x86.x86_64.zip).  Do NOT install the 12.10 "Stable" driver - it will break your install.
- After your install, you can get rid of the AMD watermark by running [this script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076381) in your terminal.

Sleep/Wake and Wifi all work out of the box.

Comment: Note: The Ubuntu certified Acer Aspire One is the old Intel Atom version not the 725 AMD C-60 APU. Second, the secure boot UEFI may make WUBI install not work. The rest of the answer looks useful though.